# string comes up as TextIOWrapper instead of a string using ast.literal_eval() function

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, dictionary

I am trying to convert a string to a dictionary using `ast.literal_eval()`.I used a website's API to retrieve data in Json format. When I printed the data to my console, and used the `type()` function, it returned it as a string (but is formated like a dictionary). I wrote the str to a json file. it looks like this:

```
{"productId":1200,"productName":"Mox Sapphire","image":"https://6d4be195623157e28848-7697ece4918e0a73861de0eb37d08968.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/1200_200w.jpg","categoryId":1,"groupId":7,"url":"http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/alpha-edition/mox-sapphire","modifiedOn":"2013-05-09T12:13:41.653","productConditions":[{"productConditionId":15346,"name":"Near Mint","language":"English","isFoil":false},{"productConditionId":317018,"name":"Damaged","language":"English","isFoil":false},{"productConditionId":332776,"name":"Moderately Played","language":"English","isFoil":false},{"productConditionId":348534,"name":"Heavily Played","language":"English","isFoil":false},{"productConditionId":364292,"name":"Lightly Played","language":"English","isFoil":false}]}
```

When I open the file and run `type()` on it, it comes out as `<class "str">`. I then try to convert it to a dictionary using the `ast.literal_eval()` function on the Json file that is a string, but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jup/PycharmProjects/WebSc/tcg_player.py", line 62, in <module>
    get_card_detail()
  File "C:/Users/Jup/PycharmProjects/WebSc/tcg_player.py", line 59, in get_card_detail
    x = json.loads(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something basic. I don't understand how it is type `TextIOWrapper` and not a string when I used `type()` and it says string. If you could help me see my (probably obvious) flaw, that would be awesome.

Comment: why don't you just `with open('my-file-location.json', 'r') as f: data = json.load(f)`, variable `data` will contain that dictionary

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky that's what I did, but the type is a string, and not a dictionary.

Comment: it works well for me. Does your json file look like exactly that json string which you provided?

Comment: Yup. I copy and pasted it directly from the console. Maybe I should start from scratch one. Maybe I messed something else up.